# Why Standard Extension Method on IEnumerables

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, extension-methods

When i use a standard **Extension Method** on a **List** such as
**Where**(...)

the result is always **IEnumerable**, and when
you decide to do a list operation such as **Foreach()**

we need to **Cast**(not pretty) or use a **ToList()** extension method that

(maybe) uses a new List that consumes more memory (is that right?):

```
List<string> myList=new List<string>(){//some data};
```

(**Edit**: this cast on't Work)

```
myList.Where(p=>p.Length>5).Tolist().Foreach(...);
```

or

```
(myList.Where(p=>p.Length>5) as List<string>).Foreach(...);
```

Which is better code or is there a third way?

**Edit:**
Foreach is a sample, Replace that with BinarySerach

```
myList.Where(p=>p.Length>5).Tolist().Binarysearch(...)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in the `Foreach`?

Comment: Foreach is a example method of list you assume BinarySearch()

Comment: As sixlettervariables points out, you should look at what your want to achieve with this. I would guess, you could do what the foreach does, right in the query, probably within the select statement.

Comment: how can foreach is replaced with select query?

Comment: In my opinion, the `ForEach` method was a bad design decision and shouldn't be used.  It screws up readability and makes it less obvious what your code's intent is.  You're effectively telling the list to do your bidding when really you're trying to do your bidding on a list.  The fact that it works so poorly with Linq is a perfect example of why the two shouldn't be mixed (and in my opinion, `.ForEach` shouldn't be used at all)

Comment: @RedHat: Why would you do a BinarySearch on a list that you just queried??

Comment: I think we all need a concrete example. RedHat, would you mind some more context?

Comment: The main problem here is that you are mixing two concepts; the LINQ (`System.Enumerable`) methods, and the `List<T>` methods, and expecting them to be interchangeable - but simply: there are fundamental differences between the two ideas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `as` is definitely not a good approach, and I'd be surprised if it works.

In terms of what is "best", I would propose `foreach` instead of `ForEach`:

```
foreach(var item in myList.Where(p=>p.Length>5)) {
    ... // do something with item
}
```

If you **desperately** want to use list methods, perhaps:

```
myList.FindAll(p=>p.Length>5).ForEach(...);
```

or indeed

```
var result = myList.FindAll(p=>p.Length>5).BinarySearch(...);
```

but note that this *does* (unlike the first) require an additional copy of the data, which could be a pain if there are 100,000 items in `myList` with length above 5.

The reason that LINQ returns `IEnumerable<T>` is that this (LINQ-to-Objects) is designed to be composable and streaming, which is **not** possible if you go to a list. For example, a combination of a few `where` / `select` etc should **not** strictly need to create lots of intermediate lists (and indeed, LINQ doesn't).

This is even more important when you consider that not all sequences are bounded; there are **infinite** sequences, for example:

```
static IEnumerable<int> GetForever() {
    while(true) yield return 42;
}
var thisWorks = GetForever().Take(10).ToList();
```

as *until* the `ToList` it is composing iterators, **not** generating an intermediate list. There are a few buffered operations, though, like `OrderBy`, which need to read all the data first. Most LINQ operations are streaming.

Answer (score 5):

One of the [design goals for LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) is to allow **composable queries** on any supported data type, which is achieved by having return-types specified using generic interfaces rather than concrete classes (such as `IEnumerable<T>` as you noted). This allows the nuts and bolts to be implemented as needed, either as a concrete class (e.g. `WhereEnumerableIterator<T>` or hoisted into a SQL query) or using the convenient `yield` keyword.

Additionally, another [design philosophy of LINQ is one of **deferred execution**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx). Basically, until you actually *use* the query, no real work has been done. This allows potentially expensive ([or infinite as Mark notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148264/why-standard-extension-method-on-ienumerables/8148379#8148379)) operations to be completed only exactly as needed.

If `List<T>.Where` returned another `List<T>` it would potentially limit composition and would certainly hinder deferred execution (not to mention generate excess memory).

So, looking back at your example, the best way to use the result of the `Where` operator depends on what you want to do with it!

```
// This assumes myList has 20,000 entries
// if .Where returned a new list we'd potentially double our memory!
var largeStrings = myList.Where(ss => ss.Length > 100);
foreach (var item in largeStrings)
{
    someContainer.Add(item);
}

// or if we supported an IEnumerable<T>
someContainer.AddRange(myList.Where(ss => ss.Length > 100));
```

Comment: Good to mention deferred execution!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make a simple foreach over a list, you can do like this:

```
foreach (var item in myList.Where([Where clause]))
{
    // Do something with each item.
}
```

Comment: .Foreach() is a exapmle, you assume BinarySearch() instead of Foreach()

Answer (score 2):

You can't cast (`as`) `IEnumerable<string>` to `List<string>`. `IEnumerable` evaluates items when you access those. Invoking `ToList<string>()` will enumerate all items in the collection and returns a new List, which is a bit of memory inefficiency and as well as unnecessary. If you are willing to use `ForEach` extension method to any collection its better to write a new `ForEach` extension method that will work on any collection.

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerableList, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach(T item in enumerableList)
    {
        action(item);
    }
}
```