# Strongly typed LINQ extension methods

Tags: c#, linq, generics, collections

I have noticed that all of the Linq extension methods `Where`, `Any`, `Take` etc. all return `IEnumerable`. For my application it would be a lot nicer if these returned an instance of the same type as the one I am calling on.

So for instance, if I call `myList.Where(...)` on a `LinkedList`, I would like to get a `LinkedList` back, on a `List` i'd like a `List` back, etc.

This becomes more annoying when I have a type like

```
class MyType
{
    public string MyField;
}

class MyCollection : List<MyType>
{
    // Some useful stuff in here
}
```

in which case I would like to be able to do

```
MyCollection source = .......
MyCollection filtered = source.Where(obj => obj.MyField != null);
```

Sadly, this won't work out of the box. However, I have come close, using the following code

```
public static ListType Filtered<ListType, ElementType>(this ListType @this, Predicate<ElementType> filter) where ListType : class, ICollection<ElementType>, new()
{
    // Arguments checks omitted

    // Create return instance
    var filtered = new ListType();

    // Apply filter for each element
    foreach (var item in @this)
    {
        if (filter(item))
            filtered.Add(item);
    }

    return filtered;
}
```

I can do (Notice the stronly typed delegate)

```
MyCollection source = .......
MyCollection filtered = source.Filtered((MyType obj) => obj.MyField != null);
```

So my question is: Why do I need the second generic argument in `Filter<ListType, ElementType>`, when I specify `where ListType : ICollection<ElementType>`? I understand I cannot use any generic types in `where` that I haven't added to the method declaration, but why is this? Is there a nicer way of doing this that I have overlooked?

Comment: For **why** it doesn't return the same type: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148264/why-standard-extension-method-on-ienumerables/8148379#8148379 - basically, I'd say: don't do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you need two type parameters because you've got two types involved: the collection type, and the element type. There's no way of saying, it's got to implement `IFoo<T>` for *some* kind of `T`, but we don't care what that `T` is.

You're *also* using both types elsewhere in the declaration: `ListType` as the return type, and `ElementType` in the predicate declaration. (This method declaration would be easier to understand if you'd followed .NET naming conventions and called them something like `TCollection` and `TElement`, by the way.)

You're *also* using both types within the method body: `item` is statically typed to be `ElementType`, and `filtered` is statically typed to be `ListType`.

It's hard to see how you would express all of this *without* both type parameters. Given that type inference lets you *call* the method without being explicit, it's not clear to me why this is a problem...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm quite new to C# so I haven't gotten too much into the changes of generics from other languages (e.g. java) yet, but I'm starting to. It's not a problem per se, but i would rather do `someField = myList.Filtered()` than `someField = new MyListType(myList.Filtered())`.

Comment: @jornb87: Well personally I'd try to avoid requiring a particular collection type until the *end* of your transformation sequence, but leaving that aside you're already using type inference in the code that you've shown.